# Treat the two set separately

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, radio-button

The woes of a programming newbie...  In my program.

I am calculating and displaying how many calories a person needs to maintain current weight. I have `2` sets of `2` `radioButtons`:  1 set is for the gender, male or female, the other set is for their activity rate, active or inactive.

With two different sets of `radioButtons`, one from each should be able to be selected, however only one radio button is being selected at a time, how can I tell the program to treat the two sets of radio buttons separately?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: You have to let everyone know more about your environment, is your project a winforms or asp.net or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use GroupBoxes to put a set of radiobuttons inside a groupbox and the other set inside another Group box

In this way every set of radiobuttons is isolated from the other set and works as expected

The following code is just an example of a form build manually, working with the designer will create an equivalent of this code for you inside the InitializeComponent method. Note how the two radiobutton sets are childs of a different container (the groupbox)

```
' A generic form
Dim f as Form = new Form()
f.Size = new Size(300, 500)

' Create a Group box
Dim b1 as GroupBox = new GroupBox()
b1.Text = "Gender"
b1.Location = new Point(0,0)

' Create two radiobutton for Gender
Dim r1 as RadioButton = new RadioButton()
r1.Text = "Male"
r1.Location = new Point(5,15)
Dim r2 As RadioButton = new RadioButton()
r2.Text = "Female"
r2.Location = new Point(5, 40)

' Add the two radiobuttons to the GroupBox control collection
b1.Controls.AddRange(new Control() {r1, r2})

' Repeat for the second set of radiobuttons
Dim b2 as GroupBox = new GroupBox()
b2.Text = "Activity Rate"
b2.Location = new Point(0,100)
Dim r3 As RadioButton = new RadioButton()
r3.Text = "Active"
r3.Location = new Point(5,15)
Dim r4 as RadioButton = new RadioButton()
r4.Text = "Inactive"
r4.Location = new Point(5,40)
b2.Controls.AddRange(new Control() {r3, r4})

' Finally add the GroupBoxes to the Form ControlsCollection
f.Controls.AddRange(new Control() {b1, b2})

f.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: That makes more sense than anything I've seen yet, thanks Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons work in groups. Separate them with a container and your good.